# Anyone know of a class that mimics Pascal's "range array"?

Tags: c++

I don't remember the exact name - I barely remember much about Pascal - but it was just an array that did some bounds checking so you could define and use something like this:

```
char arr[20..40];
```

and it would throw an out-of-bounds exception if you accessed element 15 or 60.

In C++ I assume it would look something more like

```
vector<char> arr(20,40);
```

This is pretty simple to do with a class wrapper around a C++ array but I was hoping someone knew of something that used a vector.  Ideally I am looking for something where the range (and size) would dynamically change if (1) a setter was called or (2) and insertion/deletion was made but (3) attempts to access an invalid element still threw an exception.

```
arr.setUpper(50);
```

and

```
arr.push_back(element);  //adjust upper array bound
```

I am not yet up to speed on C++11 arrays so maybe they do something like this already?

Comment: `vector`'s `at()` already does range checking, so it would be pretty simple (something like `return data.at(index-lower);`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ arrays simply do not support custom bounds like Pascal does.  They always start at index 0 and end at index length-1.  If you want Pascal-like indexing, you have to implement it yourself, eg:

```
template<typename T, const int LowBound, const int HighBound>
class RangedArray
{
private:
    T m_arr[HighBound-LowBound+1];

    void CheckBounds(const int index)
    {
        if ((index < LowBound) || (index > HighBound))
            throw std::out_of_range();
    }

public:
    int low() const { return LowBound; }
    int high() const { return HighBound; }

    T operator[](const int index) const
    {
        CheckBounds(index);
        return m_arr[index-LowBound];
    }

    T& operator[](const int index)
    {
        CheckBounds(index);
        return m_arr[index-LowBound];
    }
};
```

.

```
RangedArray<char, 20, 40> arr;
arr[20] // OK
arr[15] // out of bounds
arr[60] // out of bounds
```

If you want something more dynamic, try this instead:

```
template<typename T, const int LowBound>
class RangedVector
{
private:
    std::vector<T> m_vec;

    void CheckBounds(const int index)
    {
        if ((index < low()) || (index > high()))
            throw std::out_of_range();
    }

public:
    int low() const { return LowBound; }
    int high() const { return m_vec.empty() ? -1 : (LowBound + m_vec.size() - 1); }

    void setHighBound(const int HighBound)
    {
        if (HighBound < LowBound)
            throw something;
        m_vec.resize(HighBound-LowBound+1);
    }

    void push_back(const T &value)
    {
        m_vec.push_back(value);
    }

    T operator[](const int index) const
    {
        CheckBounds(index);
        return m_vec[index-LowBound];
    }

    T& operator[](const int index)
    {
        CheckBounds(index);
        return m_vec[index-LowBound];
    }
};
```

.

```
RangedVector<char, 20> arr;
arr.setHighBound(40);
arr[20] // OK
arr[15] // out of bounds
arr[60] // out of bounds
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid rolling my own but this is a very good starting point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector::at` will perform [bounds checking](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) and an exception of type `std::out_of_range` will be thrown if an invalid location is used. `operator[]` does not perform bounds checking.

In your example, `vector<char> arr(20,40)` would construct a vector of 20 integers with the value of 40. This is known as the repetitive sequence constructor.